# Confidence Interval for Regression Coefficient ,$\beta$

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, statistical-inference, sampling

In the book 'Applied regression Analysis' by Draper/Smith, it is written that :

#### Obtain individual $100(1-\alpha)\%$ confidence interval for the various parameters separately from the formula

$$\hat\beta_i\pm t(n-p,1-\frac{\alpha}{2})se(\hat\beta_i)$$

Degrees of freedom due to error is $n-p$ and degrees of freedom due to residual is $p-1$.

Why am i considering error degrees of freedom while constructing  $100(1-\alpha)\%$ confidence interval for $\beta_i$ ?

Comment: Hi, was all ok with your analysis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confidence interval for a regression coefficient $\beta$ follows a $t$ distribution with $ n-p$ degrees of freedom. To calculate it the following steps are necessary:

- identify the parameter $\hat\beta_i$ for which you want to calculate the CI;
- specify a confidence level (e.g., 95% 99% etc...), which corresponds to $1-\alpha$);
- calculate the critical probability $1-\alpha/2$ (note that we have to halve $\alpha$ because the margin error will be doubled for the calculation of the confidence interval); for example,  if you specified a 99% confidence level, you get a $1-0.99/2=0.995$ critical probability;
- calculate the critical value: this is the t score having $n-2$ degrees of freedom and a cumulative probability equal to the critical probability (we indicate it as $ t(n-p,1-\frac{\alpha}{2})$;
- take the standard error of the parameter $se\hat\beta_i$ (it is usually given directly by the software in the regression output);
- calculate the margin of error as the product  of the critical value and the standard error  of the parameter, and use it to calculate confidence intervals as $$\hat\beta_i\pm t(n-p,1-\frac{\alpha}{2})se(\hat\beta_i)$$

Comment: I apology. I have not understood yet "Why does the confidence interval for a regression coefficient $\beta$ follow a $t$ distribution with `$ n-p$` degrees of freedom?"

Comment: The t distribution of $\beta$ coefficients is one of the assumptions of linear regression. The number of freedom degrees is classically defined by the number of independent values that go into the estimate minus the number of parameters:  in this case, the total sample size $N$ minus the number of regressors $p$.